# How to specify children classes to use their type?

Tags: c#, generics, object-oriented-analysis

Lets say I have a class such as this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public void Access(Foo foo)
    {
        /*
        if (foo is same type as implemented)
            AccessIfSameImplementation(foo);
        else
            AccessIfDifferentImplementation(foo);
        */
    }

    protected abstract void AccessIfSameImplementation(Foo foo);

    private void AccessIfDifferentImplementation(Foo foo)
    {
         //do stuff with the different implementations
    }
}
```

So the method `Access` takes a type of itself, by definition it will be an implementation in which we don't really care what it is as long as it inherits from `Foo`... But I want this method to check if the object passed in is the same type as its implementation.

Like so:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override void AccessIfSameImplementation(Foo foo)
    {
        // TODO: How do I force foo to always be a Bar
        // do specific Bar stuff
    }
}
```

Currently I have a `Name` field that indicates if the passed in `foo.Name` is the same as the current `Name` Besides that I thought about using generics but again don't think that's the right approach to this problem.

**EDIT:**

A little background on the actual structures I'm using.

The `Foo` class defined above is representative of a factory that creates a set of objects `List<X> objs` these objects are generated by the properties of the implemented `Foo` object. Now I have some other class comparing these factories but I don't wish for the factories to be, *bloated out by generating them all. So instead of *bloating the factories out I simply check if they have the same implementation, if so compare properties defined by the abstract comparer otherwise *blowout. I will add more later when I have some time.

If anyone has a better title please recommend one.

Comment: There is no such thing as a private abstract method, so I changed it to protected.

Comment: @Dan oops my bad, copying bits of code doesn't help.

Comment: Have you looked at using constraints with generics?  My head's been in SQL all day long today so I'm not sure that would even work, but the thought crossed my mind.

Comment: @Tim It also crossed mine, but it doesn't force the implementation to that type. `protected abstract void AccessIfSameImplementation<T>(T foo) where T : Foo` is essentially the same as `protected abstract void AccessIfSameImplementation(Foo foo)`

Comment: Why are you needing to do that? Having to make conditional code based on actual type is usually a sign of a design flaw. For differentiated behavior per type you may want to look into the [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern, which is a bit more elegant than if statements and casting.

Comment: For better comparisons. My actual structures are factories which create a set of objects. The method that uses a type comparison is the compare, if both the factories are the same then I can compare the fields of the object, otherwise I can just create the set of objects and compare those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aright so I guess I just can't think things entirely through. All that needs to be done is a type comparison directly in the public method `Access`

```
public void Access(Foo foo)
{
    if (GetType() == foo.GetType) //Duh...
    {
         AccessIfSameImplementation(foo);
    }
    else
    {
         AccessIfDifferentImplementation(foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what your intention is, but you can't change the signature of an abstract method in the child class. One thought would be to do an argument check and throw an exception if you ever got an inappropriate foo:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public void Access(Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo.GetType() == GetType())
        {
            AccessIfSameImplementation(foo);
        }
        else
        {
            AccessIfDifferentImplementation(foo);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void AccessIfSameImplementation(Foo foo);

    private void AccessIfDifferentImplementation(Foo foo)
    {
        //do stuff with the different implementations
    }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }

    protected override void AccessIfSameImplementation(Foo foo)
    {
        var bar = foo as Bar;

        if (bar == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument foo is not of type Bar");
        }

        //Do Bar stuff below
        bar.Baz = "Yay!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to accomplish this while using the parent class to essentially see if the parameter is the same implementation, if so call its override method else call a default hidden method.

Comment: I put up an edit. Btw if you do use the `GetType() == foo.GetType()` theirs no point in checking for null in the derived class if indeed its always a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.  Keep your abstract class abstract, but give the `Access` method a default implementation that is `Foo` agnostic.  Leave it up the a child class to provide custom implementation that uses members of that child class.  You could also make it optional for the child class to fall back on the default logic implemented in the base class:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public virtual void Access(Foo foo)
    {
        // perform the default implementation here, but mark as virtual to enable a child class to override it.
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override void Access(Foo foo)
    {
        var bar = foo as Bar;
        if (bar != null)
        {
            // If you get here, that means foo is a Bar.
            // Just use bar now and ignore foo.
        }
        else
        {
            // Fall back on the base classes implementation
            base.Access(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Originally this is how I had it, but I didn't want my children classes to take other children because I don't want those children to know about those other children ;)

Comment: In the base class method, they'll both be `Foo` instances.  It's only in the child class that you'd check for a specific implementation type.  Obviously, you wouldn't check for type other than the implementation you're in.  That way, all of those children don't have to know about each other.

Comment: I was just trying to get away from forcing library users to understand that they Should only ever compare the same factories.